# Angular promise callback not firing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I have this app that uploads a file to a server using  $cordovaFileTransfer and then sends data about the file to the same server. The file is transferred fine. The data is then sent to the server, and the server responds.  But the response does not make it back to the promise callback. Why?

```
$scope.sendPost = function(data) {

  //first upload a file then send more data about the file
  $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://example.com', 'myfile.txt', options)
    .then(function(result) {
      var promise = MyFactory.sendFileData(data);
    });

promise.then(function(response) {
  //we never make it to here
});

}
```

and in MyFactory:

```
service.sendFileData = function(data) {
  return $http({
    //bunch of parameters. This function works, data is sent to the server and a response received
  }).then(function(response) {
    //this is fired when the response is received from the server. All is good so far.

  return.response.data

  });
}
return service;
```

Comment: I'm I the only one seeing unmatched brackets everywhere in the code?

Comment: thanks @AbdoAdel ...added the missing brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$cordovaFileTransfer.upload` returns a promise object, which you could use to build up promise chaining mechanism.

**Code**

```
$scope.sendPost = function(data) {

    //get hold on `upload` function promise
    var promise = $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://example.com', 'myfile.txt', options)
    .then(function(result)) {
          //return MyFactory.sendFileData promise here which will follow promise chaining
          return MyFactory.sendFileData(data);
        });
    //promise.then will get call once `MyFactory.sendFileData` complete it
    promise.then(function(response) {
        //will get called once `sendFileData` complete its promise
    });
}
```

Comment: @lilbiscuit Glad to help you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

its because you're relaying on another ***promise's*** callback to initiate a the promise and.. most probably before the promise gets initialized you are attaching a callback tot it.. so at the time of you attaching the callback, the promise is not yet initialized i.e. `promise` is `null`.. so in your console you'll see an error..

try doing some thing  like

```
var x = function(response) {
  //we'll make it to here now...
}
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://example.com', 'myfile.txt', options)
    .then(function(result)) {
      var promise = MyFactory.sendFileData(data);
      promise.then(x);
     });
```

You should follow @PankajParkar solution though it's a better approach...

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.sendPost = function(data) {

//first upload a file then send more data about the file
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://example.com', 'myfile.txt', options)
.then(function(result)) {
  return MyFactory.sendFileData(result.data);
})
.then(function(response) {

});
```